# Examples of principal bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, principal-bundles

I´m actually working with principal bundles and I´m looking for particular examples. For instance, a principal bundle of structure group $Gl(n)$ is just a vector bundle. I´m wondering what happens if we consider for instance $G=\mathbb{G}_{a}$ the additive group. What is a principal bundle of structure group $\mathbb{G}_{a}$? Is there any relation with principal bundles over projective spaces? Thank you for your time

Comment: Isn't the multiplicative group just $\mathrm{GL}(1)$? So, it should just give you line bundles.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say the additive group